# How to solve this context free grammar

Tags: automation, context-free-grammar, pushdown-automaton

Give a Context free grammar for

> {**w** | **w** is an element of {a, b, c, d}* such that # of a+ # of b = # of c + # of D}
>
> how do i approach this question...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How's about this one:

```
S -> A C S     
S -> A S C                   
S -> S A C                 

S -> C A S     
S -> C S A                   
S -> S C A

S -> 
A -> a|b
C -> c|d
```

(There may be a more elegant solution...)

*As to **how** to approach these, in my opinion the key insight is usually in the grouping (here A and C), but the I think the best way to learn is to see lots of examples and attempt lots of problems - e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12934367/1240268).*